# HibernateTemplate in spring orm 4.0.6 is missing saveOrUpdateAll

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-orm

I am trying to migrate our app from spring 2.5.6 to recent version of spring  which is 4.0.6.  One of the issues I faced is HibernateTemplate is missing saveOrUpdateAll. I could change it manually but I need to change it close 200 files. I don't know why Spring removed it instead of deprecating it. Anyone have workaround for this? I believe this is the starting of painful migration.

Comment: The Spring 2.5.6 documentation of HibernateTemplate already advised to avoid the usage of HibernateTemplate completely.

Comment: Seems like Spring sort of says don't use hibernate :-)

Comment: No, not at all. It says that the Hibernate native API doesn't need to be wrapped into a HibernateTemplate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Spring 2.5 to 4.0 is quite a big jump. And Spring **DID** deprecate that method. If you look at the [API for Spring 3](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateOperations.html#saveOrUpdateAll%28java.util.Collection%29), that method has been marked as deprecated and removed completely in Spring 4. Even more, in Spring 2.5 it was, also, deprecated, see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateOperations.html#saveOrUpdateAll%28java.util.Collection%29).

So, in your Spring 2.5.6 project you were already using a deprecated method.