# org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Unknown entity: java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, arraylist

When my project run on spring 2.5 and hibernate 3.2 it works fine.After updating spring version to 4.1.6 and hibernate version to 3.6.1 i got the following error:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.util.ArrayList

My DAO function is :

```
public void updateAll(Collection<EntityType> collection) {
    try {
    getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdateAll(collection);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("updateAll :"+e);
    }
}
```

Configuration is :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" id="sessionFactory">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.cptu.egp.eps.model.table.TblCountryMaster</value>
             </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">                  net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class"> net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">5</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">16</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">25</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_statement</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

<bean  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate" id="hibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateInterceptor" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

My Entity Mapping class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_TenderEstCost", schema = "dbo")
public class TblTenderEstCost implements java.io.Serializable {

private int estCostLotId;
private TblTenderMaster tblTenderMaster;

public TblTenderEstCost() {
}

public TblTenderEstCost(int estCostLotId, TblTenderMaster tblTenderMaster) {
    this.estCostLotId = estCostLotId;
    this.tblTenderMaster = tblTenderMaster;
}

@Id
 @GeneratedValue(generator = "TblTenderEstCostSequence", strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "TblTenderEstCostSequence", sequenceName = "tblTenderEstCost_sequence", allocationSize = 25)

@Column(name = "estCostLotId", unique = true, nullable = false)
public int getEstCostLotId() {
    return this.estCostLotId;
}

public void setEstCostLotId(int estCostLotId) {
    this.estCostLotId = estCostLotId;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "tenderId", nullable = false)
public TblTenderMaster getTblTenderMaster() {
    return tblTenderMaster;
}

public void setTblTenderMaster(TblTenderMaster tblTenderMaster) {
    this.tblTenderMaster = tblTenderMaster;
}
```

}`

Comment: May you put the code which cause the error?

Comment: Show the entity mapping please.

Comment: can you try replacing you annotatedClasses with 
`<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.cptu.egp.eps.model.table" />` ?

Comment: getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdateAll(collection); this line of code generate the error @BlitheHuang

Comment: I tried but same error @DeendayalGarg

Comment: I added the Model class. Please check it @dambros

Comment: @Ahsan02 I think the `saveOrUpdateAll` method is deprecated nad no longer suppoted. See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296615/hibernatetemplate-in-spring-orm-4-0-6-is-missing-saveorupdateall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source code, there isn't saveOrUpdateAll() method in 4.1.6., and it's also deprecated in spring 3.

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-orm/4.1.6.RELEASE/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/HibernateTemplate.java#HibernateTemplate

It looks like you pass the collection to saveOrUpdate(), and hibernate can't find the mapping setting.

Comment: Then what could be the possible alternative?

Comment: use foreach and saveOrUpdate(), I guess.